# How to merge rows with a pair wise relationship in SQL into a singular row

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, pivot

I have a large table called trading_orders, which contains information regarding to transactions made by users on a trade marketplace. Each order is a separate row entry into the table, and as such opening and closing orders are separate. Individual order ids are captured for each entry, and for closing trades, a column called linked_order_id contains the corresponding opening order_id. If the order is an opening, this column contains a negative 1.

I would like to have each pair of open and closing orders displayed on the same row with each column prefixed by the trade type (opening/closing)

from the initial table, I can get the following table:

```
+------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
| ORDER_TYPE | ORDER_DIRECTION | TRADE_PRICE | ORDER_ID  | LINKED_ORDER_ID |
+------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
| closing    | buy             |      1.1234 | O1232     | O2789           |
| opening    | sell            |      1.1239 | O2789     | -1              |
| closing    | sell            |       345.9 | O3841     | O1270           |
| closing    | sell            |       12.55 | O1284     | O8923           |
| opening    | buy             |       345.8 | O1270     | -1              |
| opening    | buy             |       12.12 | O8923     | -1              |
+------------+-----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+
using this query
SELECT
  ORDER_TYPE,
  ORDER_DIRECTION,
  TRADE_PRICE,
  ORDER_ID,
  LINKED_ORDER_ID
FROM
  trading_orders
```

From this point, I would then like to pair orders using the relationship between ORDER_ID and LINKED_ORDER_ID into a table such as:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
| OPENING_ORDER_DIRECTION | CLOSING_ORDER_DIRECTION | OPENING_TRADE_PRICE | CLOSING_TRADE_PRICE | OPENING_ORDER_ID | CLOSING_ORDER_ID |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
| buy                     | sell                    |               12.12 |               12.55 | O8923            | O1284            |
| buy                     | sell                    |               345.8 |               345.9 | O1270            | O3841            |
| sell                    | buy                     |              1.1239 |              1.1234 | O2789            | O1232            |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

My first thought is to wrap the initial query in a WITH statement, the do some form of self join on the ids, but am unable to determine the logic to get the table I want.
Example:

```
WITH temp_table AS(
SELECT
  ORDER_TYPE,
  ORDER_DIRECTION,
  TRADE_PRICE,
  ORDER_ID,
  LINKED_ORDER_ID
FROM
  trading_orders)
SELECT
  ...
```

where ... contains the logic for the self join.

Can anyone help me determine this?

Comment: I think this is a pretty straightforward join on the table, no need for anything complicated, just select ... From trading_orders open join trading_orders close on close.linked_order_id = open.order_id. you could add a where clause to restrict based on linked_order_id value of -1, but I don't think that would be required because the join would naturally filter those out as long as there is no row with order_id -1. I might be missing something here though as I think this is quite straightforward

Comment: Regarding column name prefixes, that's just up to you what you call columns eg with query above you might  select open.order_direction as ooening_order_direction, close.order_direction as closing_order_direction etc

Comment: @Chris Thank you for your commenting, GMBs response below worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self-join: the idea is to start from opening orders (identified by `-1` in `linked_order_id`), then bring the corresponding closing order with a `join`:

```
select
    o.order_direction   opening_order_direction,
    c.order_direction   closing_order_direction,
    o.trade_price       opening_trade_price,
    c.trade_price       closing_trade_price,
    o.order_id          opening_order_id,
    c.order_id          closing_order_id
from trading_orders o
left join trading_orders c 
    on c.linked_order_id = o.order_id
where o.linked_order_id = -1
```

Another solution is conditional aggregation:

```
select
    max(case when linked_order_id =  -1 then order_direction end) opening_order_direction,
    max(case when linked_order_id <> -1 then order_direction end) closing_order_direction,
    max(case when linked_order_id =  -1 then trade_price     end) opening_trade_price,
    max(case when linked_order_id <> -1 then trade_price     end) closing_trade_price,
    max(case when linked_order_id =  -1 then order_id        end) opening_order_id,
    max(case when linked_order_id <> -1 then order_id        end) closing_order_id
from trading_orders
group by case when linked_order_id = -1 then order_id else linked_order_id end
```

The `group by` clause dynamically decides which column should be used; then the `select` clause picks the value from the relevant row to put it in the corresponding column.

Comment: thank you very much, both solutions worked perfectly, but seems like the self join has a slight performance benefit over conditional aggregation case.